# Unable to separate commas during pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to read a csv file separated by commas, and I am writing this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("UECM_5year.csv",encoding = "latin-1")
```

It is printing me something like this:

```
    Tarih,"Saat","UEÇM (MWh)"
0   01/01/2015,"00:00","23.137,18"
1   01/01/2015,"01:00","21.455,39"
```

It is not seperated by the read_csv function, so I want to learn what is causing the problem, is it the encoding style?

edit:This is the csv file I use. It is a comma separated csv file.
[image]

Comment: Could you provide as an example a piece of your CSV file instead of its representation obtained after pandas' read_csv?

Comment: Please provide the CSV as actual text, not as a picture. A picture of Excel mainly begs the question what perverse alterations Excel has done when it opened the file. Pictures of text are a nuisance anyway; see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `sep` argument:

```
df = pd.read_csv("UECM_5year.csv",encoding = "latin-1", sep=',')
```

Comment: I tried sep argument but it does not work, I assume that commas can not be seen for the read_csv argument.